# Getting rid of Sitecore link prefix (sitecore/content/..)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a Sitecore solution with multiple sites. All sites are setup in SiteDefinition.Config, and i can enter all the sites correctly.

My problem is that the internal links on the sites (navigations etc.) prefixes 'sitecore/content/*sitename*/' to all my links.

i have tried almost all the fixes/solutions i could think off - but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you running? Are you seeing this with all Link fields as well as Rich Text fields?

Comment: It is a Sitecore 6.2. And yes, it does the same for both my navigation (using xslt and sc:path) and links inserted in the Rich Text Editor - all with the same prefix.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could provide the code from SiteDefinition.Config.

Comment: It's possible your config requires this... otherwise the links could be ambiguous. Are you linking to items across sites?

Answer (score 0):

Is your

```xml
<setting name="Rendering.SiteResolving" value="true" />
```

set?

Comment: Yes - it is set to true (default value)

Answer (score 0):

Are your site definitions setup to use different values for the `rootPath` attribute?

```xml
<site name="mysite1" rootPath="/sitecore/content/mysite1" startItem="/home" hostName="mysite1.com" ... />
<site name="mysite2" rootPath="/sitecore/content/mysite2" startItem="/home" hostName="mysite2.com" ... />
```

Comment: Here's an example of a site.config:

Comment: <site name="sc_site" patch:before="site[@name='scheduler']" hostName="mydomain.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/mysite" startItem="frontpage" language="en" device="Default" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false">

Comment: See Bryan's question. Are you linking across sites? Do you see the same results if you write some code that uses LinkManager?

Comment: I am linking across 'internal' sites, but the problem occurs in all links (navigation, where xsl is used, links inserted in RTE etc.

Comment: Had any usefull comments to this question yet? I'm having the same issue for some of our websites that use multiple site config with internal linking from one to another website.

Comment: Have you tried using a piece of code to generate a URL with the SiteResolving option on? Sitecore may not be attempting to resolve the site's url and thus is including the full content path. In general, I use a method or two to generate all the internal URLs for the Sitecore sites. It essentially boils down to `options.SiteResolving = true; return LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options);`

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that this configuration to get this **it is case sensitive** (including site name, item names etc, attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem however mine only occurred when the links were between internal sites. I wrote 2 blog posts ([post #1](http://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/using-cross-site-links-dynamic-links/), [post #2](http://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/using-cross-site-links-aka-dynamic-links-part-2/)) that detail the solution i used. In short, it involves extending Sitecore's LinkProvider...

Answer (score -1):

if you want to create links the way you want you have to use a LinkManager Config and then get url using the GetDynamicUrl method.

```
Sitecore.Links.LinkUrlOptions options = new LinkUrlOptions();
options.Site = "Site1";
string portalUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Item, options);
```

Hope it helps.